# NullPointerException Can't see my error

Tags: nullpointerexception

http://pastebin.com/TiEHMhy1

There is my code ^^^

Basically whenever i run my code, i get this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.rhys.game.Game.render(Game.java:126)
    at net.rhys.game.Game.run(Game.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I cant see whats wrong but when i debug it points me to this line in another class `screen.render(pixels, 0, WIDTH); (Line 126)`

If you need the other class it is here

http://pastebin.com/WJ5j4Hj5

the other class
http://pastebin.com/uRP6mWMv

Don't think it's relevant

Comment: new Game().start(); but where is init called?

Comment: Please Mark it as resolved